# Let A, B, and C be events such that $P[A|C] = .05$ and $P[B|C] = .05$. Which of the following statements must be true?

Tags: probability

$P[AB|C] = 0.05^{2}$

$P[A'B'|C]\geq 0.90$

$P[A\cup B|C]\leq 0.05$

$P[A'\cup B'|C]\geq 1-(0.05)^{2}$

$P[A\cup B|C]\geq 0.10$

The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate these individual statements so as to make easy comparisons. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any additional information: are these events disjoint or independent?

Comment: @Alex There is no other information. I'm not sure if we can assume independence or of independence is implicitly stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's part of the solution:

In case $A$ and $B$ are NOT disjoint:
$$
P(A \cup B|C)=P(A|C)+P(B|C)-P(A \cap B|C) \leq P(A|C)+P(B|C)=0.1
$$
In case $A$ and $B$ are independent:

$$
P(A \cap B|C)=P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)=.05^2
$$
Can you handle from here?